# Cannot type anything in virtual terminal

Tags: virtual-terminal

When I press ctrl-alt-F1 (F2, etc), I get black screen with cursor.
If I try to type anything, nothing happens: cursor doesn't move. If I hit "enter", nothing happens too. But I'm able to return to GUI with ctrl-alt-F7

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 LTS with latest updates.

Any ideas?

Comment: try any of this : `CTRL+X`, `CTRL+C`, `CTRL+(anything)`

Comment: ctrl-c ctrl-v works

Comment: it helped then ?

Comment: no, sorry. i mean keyboard keys work in GUI, not in vt

Comment: Try them in `VT` and lets see then.

Comment: nothing happens in vt when i press <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd> <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd> <kbd>ctrl-x</kbd>